# Getting problem while comparing string in Drools XLS decision table

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-fusion, drools-flow

[image: libreOffice screenshot]

In cell B11 I am trying to compare my data with below column by using `$1`, but it is not working, the issue occurs only for String data I think.
Can anyone give me right explanation/reason that why compare is not working?

Instead, if I write:

```
country== or country
```

then comparing is done successfully. Why?

Comment: Please remove the optaplanner tag, as this appears unrelated.

Comment: You should be using `$param`, not `$1`. [See docs](https://docs.drools.org/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#decision-tables-rule-table-entries-ref).